# How to remove multilevel index in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe as given:

```
df = {'TYPE' : pd.Series(['Advisory','Advisory1','Advisory2','Advisory3']),
 'CNTRY' : pd.Series(['IND','FRN','IND','FRN']),
 'VALUE' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["CNTRY"],columns=["TYPE"]).reset_index()
```

After pivoting, how can I get the dataframe having columns and `df` to be like the below; removing the multilevel index, `VALUE`

```
Type|CNTRY|Advisory|Advisory1|Advisory2|Advisory3
0     FRN     NaN      2.0      NaN     4.0 
1     IND     1.0      NaN      3.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can add parameter `values`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index="CNTRY",columns="TYPE", values='VALUE').reset_index()
print (df)
TYPE CNTRY  Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2  Advisory3
0      FRN       NaN        2.0        NaN        4.0
1      IND       1.0        NaN        3.0        NaN
```

And for remove columns name [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index="CNTRY",columns="TYPE", values='VALUE') \
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  CNTRY  Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2  Advisory3
0   FRN       NaN        2.0        NaN        4.0
1   IND       1.0        NaN        3.0        NaN
```

But maybe is necessary only `pivot`:

```
df = df.pivot(index="CNTRY",columns="TYPE", values='VALUE') \
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  CNTRY  Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2  Advisory3
0   FRN       NaN        2.0        NaN        4.0
1   IND       1.0        NaN        3.0        NaN
```

because [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) aggregate duplicates by default aggregate function `mean`:

```
df = {'TYPE' : pd.Series(['Advisory','Advisory1','Advisory2','Advisory1']),
 'CNTRY' : pd.Series(['IND','FRN','IND','FRN']),
 'VALUE' : pd.Series([1., 4., 3., 4.])}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print (df)
  CNTRY       TYPE  VALUE
0   IND   Advisory    1.0
1   FRN  Advisory1    1.0 <-same FRN and Advisory1 
2   IND  Advisory2    3.0
3   FRN  Advisory1    4.0 <-same FRN and Advisory1 

df = df.pivot_table(index="CNTRY",columns="TYPE", values='VALUE')
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
TYPE   Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2
CNTRY                                
FRN         0.0        2.5        0.0
IND         1.0        0.0        3.0
```

Alternative with `groupby`, aggregate function and `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby(["CNTRY","TYPE"])['VALUE'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
      .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  CNTRY  Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2
0   FRN       0.0        2.5        0.0
1   IND       1.0        0.0        3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `set_index` with `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['CNTRY', 'TYPE']).VALUE.unstack().reset_index()

TYPE CNTRY  Advisory  Advisory1  Advisory2  Advisory3
0      FRN       NaN        2.0        NaN        4.0
1      IND       1.0        NaN        3.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(level=1)`

Change the level depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df.droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
```